# Is every object rounded to the same size in Java?

Tags: java, object-oriented, memory, data-types

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/416617/1527084) every object in Java is of the same size? Is the answer talking about the object itself or the reference to the object?

Here's the statement:

> every object size is rounded to 16 bytes in Hotspot, so an object with
>   a single byte field will take up precisely the same space as a single
>   object with a long or double field;

I am completely baffled by the claim in this statement. So many upvotes to this answer further befuddled me.

Can some one please explain what is meant by the above statement?

Comment: Note that this **specifically** mentions HotSpot and does *not* necessarily apply to any other JVM implementation (not even to newer and/or older versions of HotSpot, or HotSpot on another platform). Numbers like these are *always* implementation specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rounded to a multiple of 16 bytes. Objects can be 16B, 32B, 48B, etc

Comment: Where is the term **multiple** mentioned?

Comment: @Geek, the multiple is implied.  Carelessly worded, admittedly, but most people can read between the lines.

Comment: "Every object size is rounded to X" means a multiple of X.  X could be "integers" or "powers of 2" or whatever, and the syntax is the same.  (What's implied is that it's rounded UP.)